# (Pandas) How to replace certain values of a column from a different dataset but leave other values in the dataset untouched?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, left-join

Let's say I have the dataset:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['number'] = [0,0,0,0,0]
df1["decade"] = ["1970", "1980", "1990", "2000", "2010"]`

print(df1)

#output:
   number decade
0       0   1970
1       0   1980
2       0   1990
3       0   2000
4       0   2010
```

and I want to merge it with another dataset:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['number'] = [1,1]
df2["decade"] = ["1990", "2010"]

print(df2)

#output:
   number decade
0       1   1990
1       1   2010
```

such that it get's values only from the decades from `df2` that have values in them and leaves the others untouched, yielding:

```
   number decade
0       0   1970
1       0   1980
2       1   1990
3       0   2000
4       1   2010
```

how must one go about doing that in pandas? I've tried stuff like `join`, `merge`, and `concat` but they all seem to either not give the desired result or not work because of the different dimensions of the 2 datasets. Any suggestions regarding which function I should be looking at?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`pandas.Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html?highlight=series%20fillna#pandas.Series.fillna) :

```
out = (
        df1[["decade"]]
            .merge(df2, on="decade", how="left")
            .fillna({"number": df1["number"]}, downcast="infer")
      )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

  decade  number
0   1970       0
1   1980       0
2   1990       1
3   2000       0
4   2010       1
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using apply?

First you create a function

```
def validation(previous,latest):
    if pd.isna(latest):
        return previous
    else:
        return latest
```

Then you can use the function dataframe.apply to compare the data in df1 to df2

```
df1['number'] = df1.apply(lambda row: validation(row['number'],df2.loc[df2['decade'] == row.decade].number.max()),axis = 1)
```

Your result:

```
   number decade
0       0   1970
1       0   1980
2       1   1990
3       0   2000
4       1   2010
```